# Save content of textarea as plain txt with .csv extension

Tags: javascript, html, file, csv, filereader

Is there a way to save content as a `txt` file with a `csv file extension` using **HTML5** ?
It shouldn't be a real csv.

Something like `{type:'text/csv'};` wont work where `{type:'text/plain'};` does.

Comment: I don't understand your question, may you give a little more details ?

Comment: I just want to create and save a file as csv but it's content shouldn't be comma separated.

Comment: I'm failing to understand why you just don't save your file as `.csv` from your favorite editor. Could you give a little more details on your question context ?

Comment: I have to add line breaks and some words before saving it as csv.
I wont do this in an editor because I don't like to do this all over again if I add something new to it. That's why I thought it should be possible to process some tasks with JS and save it with html5.

Comment: I see. However, if you're doing this for yourself (ie : on your local machine), javascript is not your best bet since it's not intended to do operations. Please note that `filereader` is useful only for reading operations. Any chance you can use a more suited language like python ?

Comment: @rojo
Thanks alot.
This was what I had been looking for.
I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `a` tag's new `download` property can work to your advantage here.  [More information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Proof of concept:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function save() {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                with (a) {
                    href='data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa(document.getElementById('csv').value);
                    download='csvfile.csv';
                }
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="csv"></textarea><button onclick="save()">Save</button>
    </body>
</html>
```