# xhrpost to download on the fly generated excel file on the server

Tags: javascript, rest, post, dojo, download

I have the below requirement.

I have a data grid, which has huge amount of data. I have a download button, when clicked data grid data has to be downloaded to an excel. This data grid data I want to send to server through a rest call using xhrpost. With this data i will construct an excel file on the fly on server side and i will return the response to the client. My client by seeing this response should open popup for downloading the response to save as the file.

I am seeing the following problems here :

1. the data is huge. so , I can't use window.open way for sending the data in GET format.
2. I don't have an URL on server which will access file, as i am generating file on the fly and sending response to client.

How will i achieve my use case to download file using xhrpost on the fly, not storing the file anywhere?

Please reply as I am breaking my head how to do this? It will be of great help.

Thanks,
Sreenivas

Comment: why would you want to send the data back from the datagrid(client) to the server? Can't you use the same request that generated the datagrid to generate the excel file on the server?

Comment: When your server generates the CSV data, set the HTTP header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="grid.csv"`.  That'll prompt the client to save with a default filename of `grid.csv`, rather than displaying the generated content within the browser.  The csv file can then be read by Excel.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No, I can't use the same data which used to generate grid, because user overrides some of the grid data items, as some of them are editable fields. so data varies. secondly, i want to pass this data to server definitely, because with this data i want to make some DB check, for making some decisions.

Comment: @rojo : I am setting the http header as you said, but my xhrpost is like this:

dojo.xhrPost(
url: someUrl,
contentType: "application/json",
load: function(response) {
});

here the response is the data from server, and for which i set HTTP header, but after getting response from server to the response variable, what do i do, so that it will open a pop up or downloads to local system?

Comment: @rojo : My point is after getting the response to client, what should i do with it, so that it will open a download prompt "save as link" or simply download the file to the default location in the local sysytem?

Comment: I just answered another question that gives me an idea about your question.  You can dynamically create an `a` tag with a `data:` stream and simulate a click on it.  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26996264/1683264) for a proof of concept.  Not that I recommend this in your situation.  If I were you, I'd use an actual form post, rather than XHR.  If you insist on XHR, though, then I guess that's your answer.  And you can remove the `content-disposition` header, as XHR can't inherently prompt a Save As dialog.

Comment: @user1918641 If that helped, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.  If not, edit your question and include your XHR code, and I'll see if I can suggest what to modify exactly.