# Creating Batch Scripts with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I'm trying to make a simple page with JS which generates Batch Scrips based on user input.
This is the prototype code and works fine with Chrome, but clicking on link with Firefox downloads the file as .txt (e.g.: file.bat.txt) and IE is completey unresponsive to the link
Where am i going wrong?
Any issues with "data:text/plain;base64,"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" download="file.bat">click here</a>
<script>
var bat_source = "@echo off\necho Hello world\npause";
document.querySelector("a").href = 'data:text/plain;base64,' + btoa(bat_source);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26996264/1683264

Comment: Thanks dude, setting 'data:text/bat;base64,' did the job for Firefox. IE still seems unresponsive, but that's okay.

Comment: By default Internet Explorer blocks JavaScript from running from local, non-HTTP-served files.  You might consider [rewriting your project as an .hta file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40289936/1683264).